# How to connect your mobile to JMeter to record scripts inspite of Company firewall

Tags: jmeter-3.2

How can i connect my mobile device to Jmeter in laptop to record native Mobile app inspite of Company Firewall.

I have tried connecting my mobile device to JMeter in my personal laptop and that was working fine. I think the issue is because of Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your laptop and Mobile is in the same wifi network or not. If it is then disabled laptop firewall (if it can be disabled) and check again. If still it won't work then you can explore Blazemeter option where you record script using proxy. Reference is "https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder".
I hope this will help you.